# aborting ajax call javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, call, abort

I use the code below from one Stackoverflow answer to abort AJAX call in JavaScript/jQuery.

```
$.xhrPool.abortAll = function () {
  // alert('aborting.... outside');

  $(this).each(function (idx, jqXHR) {
    //jqXHR.abort();

    if (jqXHR && jqXHR.readyState != 4) {
        alert('aborting.... outside');
        jqXHR.abort();
    }
  });
  $.xhrPool.length = 0

  clearTimeout(timeoutOfCall);
  timeoutOfCall = null;
};
```

But, when I call this function like this :

```
$.xhrPool.abortAll();
```

it generate error in "unknown property" in IE 9 and also not working in Chrome.
It is only working in FF.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Abort Ajax requests using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your whant to stop specific ajax call and your jquery is 1.5.1 or newest your can use method "abort" of jqXHR object.

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax(your ajax call);
jqxhr.abort();
```

Comment: Ya, 'abort()' will stop client (browser) listening to a response from server. Problem is that it won't stop the server itself to generate the response's request. A other way will be to resend request to tell server to stop to handle previous request. That's make a extra call to server wich is most of time not necessary. It's really depends of which kind of previous request was made...

Comment: no, i want to stop all the call which are pending and created with setinterval function.

i am working on one GPS system app.
so, i want to update device info on map after every  30 sec.
so, when i change the device, all the ajax call pending for previous device should be aborted.

Comment: Oh, so i misunderstand your question.

Comment: Hi Vasily,
will this code work only with 1.5.1 jquery version ??
not supported with higher version like 1.7.1,1.8.1 ???

Comment: hi all,
it's working now.
i had added 2 var like :
var xhrPool = []; 
$.xhrPool = [];
i just removed "var xhrPool = [];" this one, and it is working now.

thanks for your time and help.